# Arrange the following:$(1.5)^n, n^{100}, (\log n)^3, \sqrt n\log n, 10^n, (n!)^2, n^{99}+n^{98}, 101^{16}$

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

Here is the question repeated: Arrange the following in order into increasing order of growth rates. $$(1.5)^n, n^{100}, (\log n)^3, \sqrt n\log n, 10^n, (n!)^2, n^{99}+n^{98}, 101^{16}$$

I graphed these functions in my calculator and think that this is the correct ordering:$$101^{16},(\log n)^3\sqrt n\log n, n^{99}+n^{98}, n^{100}, (1.5)^n, 10^n, (n!)^2$$

(I only used my calculator for the log graphs.)

Comment: Nope. Graphing does not help, because your calculator never graphs near infinity! (Remember that any exponential function will grow faster than any polynomial, any positive power of $x$ will grow faster than any logarithm, etc. That means $101^{16}$ is too far left.)

Comment: Scratch that comment about $101^{16}$; it's a constant ... It looks right to me now.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct because
$101^{16}$ is fixed in terms of growing.
$n^{100}$ is slower than $1.5^{n}$.
And $(n!)^{2}$ is significantly large.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. To compare the logarithm you should notice that 
$$\lim_{x->\infty}\frac{(\log(x))^p}{x}=0$$ 
for any positive constant $p$ and from this you immediately see that $(\log n)^3$ has smaller rate that $\sqrt n\log n$ and both have smaller order than all polynomials.